# OpenGeo - deploying a web app

Tags: boundless-suite, jetty

When executing: `suite-sdk deploy` procedure I keep getting the following errors:

```
Checking provided application path.
Building application resources for 'C:\xxx\xxx\Sites\mySite'.
Aug 04, 2015 1:08:45 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
WARNING: input.js:79235: WARNING - Parse error. Non-JSDoc comment has annotations. Did you mean to start it with '/**'?
    /* @preserve

Aug 04, 2015 1:08:45 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
SEVERE: input.js:72815: ERROR - Parse error. Internet Explorer has a non-standard intepretation of trailing commas. Arrays will have the wrong length and objects will not parse at all.
        }],
         ^
...few more of the same errors...

Aug 04, 2015 1:08:45 PM com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager printSummary
   WARNING: 6 error(s), 1 warning(s)
    Error: Unable to compile source. (C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\sdk\lib\buildkit\lib\buildkit\closure.js#110)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\sdk\lib\buildkit\lib\buildkit\closure.js:110 (anonymous)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\sdk\lib\buildkit\lib\buildkit\closure.js:137 (anonymous)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\sdk\lib\buildkit\lib\buildkit\build.js:56 (main)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\sdk\lib\buildkit\lib\buildkit\build.js:73


BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenGeo\sdk\build.xml:209: Java returned: -1

Total time: 8 seconds
```

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this? I  cannot find any decent answers on Google regarding this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a trailing comma in your code somewhere. Use a linter to find it.

Comment: What a mission to find those little buggers. Thanks for the quick response.